# blank app without showing any error

Tags: android

this is my image downloading app displaying the images downloaded from image url and displaying them in a listView.
the app is running fine and not showing any error but the display is blank and i cant see anything..

ImageDownloader:

```
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            if (connection.getContentType().contains("image")) {
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

RowItem:

```
public class RowItem {

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public RowItem(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

CustomListViewAdapter:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(rowItem.getBitmap());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

    ListView listView;

    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("Flag 1");
        addUrls();
        System.out.println("Flag 2");
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {

            ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();

            imageDownloader.execute(urls.get(i));

            bitmaps.add(imageDownloader.getBitmap());

            System.out.println("Size"+bitmaps.size());
        }

        System.out.println("Flag 3");
        rowItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(bitmaps.get(i));
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        System.out.println("Flag 4");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("Flag 5");
    }

    public void addUrls() {

        urls.add("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXEZRoYOhIJxL5foNz_NlatDlgYStzZgVIiKuo6vtRtz2wY-8b4Q");
        urls.add("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFL3WYbqNOX-dwjtT1LroBlY5W-3YuwSIuCMRaLpnjMXbVPEJy");
        urls.add("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQiwgrJeAJN-7lcy92N51uP7XzccK_p-fTSJNCXPLPSVih8wqPf");
        urls.add("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT19dYLCEZlMRqojedJB-05jTrflD74nasvkXs-SdVeyM2BEpCSFA");
        urls.add("http://wallpaperswide.com/download/high_tech_earth-wallpaper-2880x1800.jpg");
        urls.add("https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg");
        urls.add("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1418489098061-ce87b5dc3aee?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=2f033882f3c25404e3f904fbfe2351be&w=1000&q=80");
        urls.add("https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/gettyimages-705351545.jpg?w=730&crop=1");

    }
}
```

ativity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.danishrizvi.test4.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so, if you want to show image from url in adapter , Then use  `Glide` for it. It will remove unnecessary code (converting in bitmap and passing it), and will work smooth.

Comment: You should send the bitmap to the main activity via `onPostExecute` of Async Task, I think when you call `bitmaps.add(imageDownloader.getBitmap());` it will return empty, debug and check

Comment: Better to use this for loading image in listview: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a library to load image from URL like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) (with memory and disk caching to avoid to download the same image everytime)

Comment: Agreed. There is almost no reason to ever do this manually - I don't know any application that I've ever worked on that had a need to manually load this stuff.

Comment: @Chris i am just a newbie and this is one of my first android apps and i am doing it this way just to understand how to do programming. I know there is better work to do this out there done by pros like you but i am just trying to learn this with the basics. So if you can help me out with that.

Comment: That's my point. It will be easier for you to learn how to do this with a library like Glide or Picasso, and then you can learn how those libraries do it behind the scenes. There is certainly value to learning how it works, but don't overwhelm yourself with too much at once.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is those lines:

```
imageDownloader.execute(urls.get(i));
bitmaps.add(imageDownloader.getBitmap());
```

Since `ImageDownloader` is `AsyncTask` it is executed in async way on another thread and by the time 2nd line is called nothing is received yet. What you really need to do is to override [AsyncTask#onPostExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) where you'll receive the result of request (bitmap) and can push it to adapter.